# PDO PDOStatement always outputs 1 in the end

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am new to PDO and have been checking around for some answers but could not find one. For some reason does the PDOStatement object always outputs 1 in the end.

For example when I do this

```
$username = 'Alexander';
$sql = "
    SELECT username, email FROM user
    WHERE
        username = :username;
";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>', print_r($result), '</pre>';
```

it outputs

```
Array
(
    [username] => Alexander
    [email] => alex@live.com
)
1
```

notice the 1 in the end. And for example when I use rowCount() to check
affected rows after update statement I get something like this

```
$username = 'martin';
$sql = "
    UPDATE user
    SET 
        username = :username
    WHERE id = 1;
";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();

$affected = $stmt->rowCount();

echo '<pre>', print_r($affected), '</pre>';
```

now this outputs not only 1 but 11 because of that extra 1 in the end that is always there no matter what. And if I do that query again I get not only 0 but 01. Is this normal? How can I distinguish between 0, 1 and 01 again because of that extra 1 that basically is there every time. I don't understand this behavior, what is exactly is the point of this extra 1 in the end?

Comment: This is because you print the return value of `print_r()` -> `echo '<pre>', print_r($result), '</pre>';`

Comment: Thanks alot I really appreciate the answer, I had no idea it was the print_r function. But what's the deal with all the down voting?

Comment: I think because a few people thought, that this question could  have been avoided by simply reading the manual about `print_r()`. But at the end nobody can tell, because *people are strange animals*, so you can't tell why they downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for everything! Have a nice day, evening or afternoon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `print_r($var, 1)` in order to remove those and return the string rather than the `true`.

In the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

> mixed print_r ( mixed $expression **[, bool $return = false ]** )
>
> When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is TRUE.

So just add that flag:

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($affected, 1), '</pre>';
//                               ^ or `true`
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea.

Comment: Why did I get down voted? Did I do something wrong? I came here because I gave up in the end.

Comment: @Alex people here are not obligated to explain their downvotes, especially for questions, since they are free. even with some good questions, they can get downvoted with no apparent reason